# How to determine the IP address of a Solaris system

Tags: unix, networking, ip-address, solaris, ip

What command do I want to issue when I want to know the IP address of the Solaris machine I'm logged onto?

Comment: Feel like this question shouldn't be closed if it has gotten `22 upvotes` and `140,000 + views`... It is clearly a useful question to people

Comment: @KellenStuart SO's primary directive is Maintaining Order - "useful" is a secondary concern 

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you're a normal user (i.e., not 'root') **`ifconfig`** isn't in your path, but it's the command you want.

More specifically: **`/usr/sbin/ifconfig -a`**

Comment: Of course, there may be many interfaces on the box, each with its own IP.

Comment: Sure. You'll generally have at least two -- the local loopback (lo0) and one or more ethernet connections (on my machine, ce0).

Comment: `-a` Apply the command to all interfaces of the specified address family. If no address family is supplied, either on the command line or by means of /etc/default/inet_type, then all address families will be selected. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/6mbb1kq31/

Answer (score 10):

```
/usr/sbin/ifconfig -a | awk 'BEGIN { count=0; } { if ( $1 ~ /inet/ ) { count++; if( count==2 ) { print $2; } } }'
```

This will list down the exact ip address for the machine

Comment: but not all if you have several

Answer (score 9):

The following worked pretty well for me:

```
ping -s my_host_name
```

Answer (score 6):

The following shell script gives a nice tabular result of interfaces and IP addresses (excluding the loopback interface)  It has been tested on a Solaris box

```
/usr/sbin/ifconfig -a | awk '/flags/ {printf $1" "} /inet/ {print $2}' | grep -v lo

ce0: 10.106.106.108
ce0:1: 10.106.106.23
ce0:2: 10.106.106.96
ce1: 10.106.106.109
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `ifconfig -a`. Look for "inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", that is your IP address

Comment: Using `ifconfig` like you would on Linux just prints the help file.

Answer (score 3):

`hostname` and `uname` will give you the name of the host. Then use `nslookup` to translate that to an IP address.

Answer (score 2):

There's also:

```
getent $HOSTNAME
```

or possibly:

```
getent `uname -n`
```

On Solaris 11 the *ifconfig* command is considered legacy and is being replaced by *ipadm*

```
ipadm show-addr
```

will show the IP addresses on the system for Solaris 11 and later.

Comment: The *getent* command takes a database as an argument. Perhaps you meant `getent hosts $HOSTNAME` or `getent hosts \`uname -n\``

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/sbin/host `hostname`
```

should do the trick. Bear in mind that it's a pretty common configuration for a solaris box to have several IP addresses, though, in which case

```
 /usr/sbin/ifconfig -a inet | awk '/inet/ {print $2}'
```

will list them all